Потому как(,) после - запятая
Нужна ли запятая в "потому как после"? И правильно ли расставлены запятые?

Андрей не спешил в гости к приятелю, потому как(,) после дегустации просроченного кефира(,) унитаз стал для него самым лучшим другом.


Правильно:
Андрей не спешил в гости к приятелю, потому как (что) после дегустации просроченного кефира / унитаз стал для него самым лучшим другом.
Это СПП с придаточным причины, союз потому как (что). Актуализации обстоятельственного оборота с предлогом после нет, пауза произносительная.
